# Polymer dom-repeat not show up as expected

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have this Polymer auto-binding template:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
<template>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items={{myItem}}>
    <span>{{item}}</span>
  </template>
</template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "my-app",
    ready: function() {
      this.myItem = [];
    },
    addItem: function(item) {
      console.log(this.myItem);
      this.myItem.push(item);
      console.log(this.myItem);
    }
  });
</script>
```

And I will call `document.querySelector("my-app").addItem("abcd")` in a javascript function. However, I don't know why these items don't get displayed. The console log functions show the intended results, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binding like `items="{{myItem}}"` only gets notified if the `myItem` collection is set to a new array. If you execute

```
document.querySelector('my-app').myItem = [1,2,3]
```

the `dom-repeat` template will be updated. But by simply adding an item with

```
document.querySelector('my-app').myItem.push(4)
```

it will not. You need to use [Polymers array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation) instead:

```
document.querySelector('my-app').push('myItem', 5)
```

Btw. i recommend to write

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myItems]]">
```

Double quotes around the items attribute, square brackets instead of curly ones because this is really only a [one-way binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding) and a pluralized property name because `myItems` is a collection of items.

Comment: I run into a strange behavior with Polymer.prototype.splice. I asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082760/polymer-prototype-splice-dont-behave-as-expected. If you know the answer please help me out. Thanks!