# Polymer.prototype.splice don't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm doing array mutation with Polymer's array mutation methods.

```
  this.allRules = [{name: "abc", enabled: true}];     

  var item = this.allRules[index];
  item.name = "abcdxfdsa";
  item.enabled = enabled;

  // console log out [Object]
  console.log(this.allRules);
  this.splice('allRules', index, 1);
  // Instead of logging out [], it logs out [splices: Object]
  console.log(this.allRules);
  this.push('allRules', item);
  // It logs out [Object, splices: Object]
  console.log(poly.allRules);
```

And the annoying thing is this. When I bind `this.allRules` into a `dom-repeat` template, such as the one below, when updated binded data, it shows the item that was spliced instead of the newly added item. So after a splice and a push, instead of getting `"abcdxfdsa"` as item name, I get `abc`, which is the value before splicing. Here is the link to a sample `dom-repeat` data binding. [Polymer dom-repeat how to notify array updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081221/polymer-dom-repeat-how-to-notify-array-updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the item should be removed from the array. The second time it logs out as `[splices: Object]` just to show more info about this array, as it has a property called [splices](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation). If you run the same thing in Firefox you will still see `[object]` so I guess this is just a Chrome console helper thing.

To get the value to be updated, one way is to wrap the `this.push` call inside a `this.async` method.

```
  this.async(function() {
    this.push('allRules', item);
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.allRules[0].name);
    // returns 1, meaning it's filled with one item again
    console.log(this.allRules.length);
  });
```

Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o4DWGxBeDHvYLskCFnk6?p=preview) for a working sample.

Comment: I ran into another annoying problem, this time with filtered array. I really appreciate your time please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150417/polymer-how-to-update-filtered-array

Comment: This is the solution I spent hours looking for. Polymer.splice only updates the template dom-repeat if the array's length actually changes. If you remove something and add something else, the length is constant, so it doesn't change; you need to use async so the length shortens first and then lengthens again

Comment: The comment by @DavidChu above was as precious as the answer itself.